# Problems with linespacing

Tags: spacing

users

I have some problems with linespacing in my thesis. One page look normal like this:

[image]

Another page look weird like this:

[image]

My preamble look like this:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,twoside]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel} 
\usepackage{layout}
\usepackage[protrusion=true,expansion=true]{microtype} 

% Different usepackages
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[lf]{MinionPro} %% MinionPro
\usepackage{icomma}
\usepackage{setspace}
\setstretch{1.1}
\usepackage{siunitx,booktabs}
\usepackage{graphicx}
%% \usepackage{tocloft} - add if customize TOC
\renewcommand{\cftsecleader}{\cftdotfill{\cftdotsep}}
\usepackage{tabu}

% Chapter
\usepackage[pagestyles ,newparttoc, explicit]{titlesec}%
\usepackage{titletoc}
\SetTracking[no ligatures = {f}]{encoding = }{100} 
\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}
\titleformat{name=\chapter}[display]{ \figureversion{lining}}{\lsstyle\Large\MakeUppercase\chaptername\enspace \LARGE\thechapter}{2ex}{\LARGE\bfseries#1}%\uppercase 
\titleformat{name=\chapter, numberless}{\lsstyle\LARGE}{}{0pt}{\MakeUppercase{#1}} \titlespacing{\chapter}{0pt}{2.5ex}{6ex}

% Table of Contents

\titlecontents{chapter}[0em]{\large\bfseries\protect\addvspace{15pt}}%\thecontentslabel\brlap[1.25\baselineskip]
{\textssc{\mdseries\MakeLowercase\chaptername~{\footnotesize\thecontentslabel}}\\\medskip}
{}%
{\hfill\contentspage}%

% item / enumerate

\usepackage{enumitem}

% HTML code

\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\definecolor{dkgreen}{rgb}{0,0.6,0}
\definecolor{gray}{rgb}{0.5,0.5,0.5}
\definecolor{mauve}{rgb}{0.58,0,0.82}

\lstset{frame=tb,
  language=Java,
  aboveskip=3mm,
  belowskip=3mm,
  showstringspaces=false,
  columns=flexible,
  basicstyle={\small\ttfamily},
  numbers=none,
  numberstyle=\tiny\color{gray},
  keywordstyle=\color{blue},
  commentstyle=\color{dkgreen},
  stringstyle=\color{mauve},
  breaklines=true,
  breakatwhitespace=true,
  tabsize=3
}


% Figure

\usepackage{chngcntr}
\counterwithout{figure}{chapter}

% More pdf-pages at same site

\usepackage{pdfpages}

% References
\usepackage[round, colon, sort, authoryear]{natbib}
\setlength{\bibsep}{0.0pt}
\setlength{\bibhang}{2em}
\bibpunct{(}{)}{;}{a}{}{}
\setcitestyle{notesep={: }}
\def\citeapos#1{\citeauthor{#1}'s (\citeyear{#1})}

% Quotes
\usepackage{csquotes}
\MakeOuterQuote{"}

% Page margins
\usepackage[left=3.5cm,right=3.5cm,top=3.5cm,bottom=3.5cm]{geometry}

% PDF background 
\usepackage{eso-pic}

% Random text
\usepackage{lipsum}

% Page style
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}% <- !
% Defining MyStyle
\fancypagestyle{MyStyle}{%
    \fancyhead{}
    \fancyfoot{}
    \fancyfoot[RO]{\small{\leftmark} \ \ \hspace{2pt} {\vrule height 10pt width 1pt} \hspace{2pt} \ \small{\thepage}}
    \fancyfoot[LE]{\small{\thepage} \ \ \hspace{2pt} {\vrule height 10pt width 1pt} \hspace{2pt} \ \lsstyle\small{\MakeUppercase{\chaptername}}\ \thechapter}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt} % Remove header rule
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{\lsstyle\uppercase{##1}}{}}
}
% Redefining the PLAIN style
\fancypagestyle{plain}{%
\fancyhead{} %Clean headers
\fancyfoot{} %Clean footers
\fancyfoot[RO]{{\vrule height 10pt width 1pt} \hspace{2pt} \ \thepage}
\fancyfoot[LE]{\thepage \ \hspace{2pt} {\vrule height 10pt width 1pt} \hspace{2pt}}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt} % Remove header rule
}


% Tabular
\usepackage{threeparttable}
\def\sym#1{\ifmmode^{#1}\else\(^{#1}\)\fi}
\includepdfset{pagecommand=\thispagestyle{plain}}
\renewcommand{\TPTnoteSettings}{\footnotesize}
\renewcommand{\TPTnoteLabel}[1]{#1}
```

Because of the text-length I only show you preamble. The rest is text and figures, where I use [ht].

Is there anyone who can help me.

Best regards

Comment: We can not reproduce your problem without seeing the code of it. And nobody wants to review that much code as you have posted. Please minimize as much as you can. Most of the code above has nothing to do with your your problem. Make a copy of your document and delete part by part of it until you see, where the issue is situated.

Comment: Two guesses: Please search your document for the word `\parskip` and please check that your figures are not surrounded by two blank lines. Just put one blank line after your figure, if you are having a paragraph change in text. You are talking about line-spacing: Is this really changing or just the distance between paragraphs. Please compare the two pages as I can't see it that easily.

Comment: Dear LaRiFaRi. Thank you for your help. The reason why I can't minimize more is because, I am using the whole preamble in my thesis - and because I don't know which of the elements who make the problem. I can see in my document, that there are different space between the paragraph - I have tried to search for the word \parskip, but it doesn't exist in my document.

Comment: Just remove line by line. E.g. `\usepackage{listings}`. If you kick this out, your problem will still be there. So we do not need this line here. If the problem vanishes, you can say "hey, I found a weird bug in `listings`" and you will have a clear issue and many interested volunteers, guaranteed.

Comment: You have not answered my question about line-spacing (which I put it a bit later in my second comment): If you really have line spacing issues, the word `\setstretch` could be a query of interest. Should not appear a second time in your document. Or maybe other commands from the package `setspace` which you are using. I do not use that package, so you will have to do a bit of documentation-reading in order to find possible culprit commands of this package.

Comment: I actually mean paragraph instead of line-spacing, but thanks for the advice and help. Will Robertson solved my problem. I should put \raggedbottom into my preamble. I am not normally working in two-sided printing, but because I change my footer it is necessary. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are many reasons this sort of spacing problem can occur. It is happening because `\flushbottom` is in effect (which it generally should be for two-sided printing), but TeX is being asked to insert a box that doesn't fit on the current page. For example:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{book}
\usepackage{lipsum,float}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-5]
\begin{figure}[H]
\rule{10em}{10em}
\end{figure}
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

The way to fix the problem is firstly to carefully check that you're not inserting large objects that have no option of floating. One example is given in the case above, but it can often occur from text that is dense with section headings, since section headings require a certain amount of vertical space to avoid having a lonely heading on the bottom of a page.

(Note that this exact reason is a very good argument to avoid using `H` floats. *Always* use proper floating figures and tables.)

If you can't avoid these situations, simply insert `\raggedbottom` into the preamble. If you still want `\flushbottom` in effect for most of the document, judicious use of `\newpage` before the offending content will also prevent the paragraphs from stretching out as shown in your example.

Comment: Thank you so much Will Robertson. "\raggedbottom" solved my problem. I am using two-sided printing because I change footer on every second page - is there other big problems by using two-sided printing, that I should be aware of? I am normally just using one-sided printing. Thank you so much again!

Comment: `\raggedbottom` is fine for text with many figures and section headings and so on. There's nothing really else that you need to watch out for, that comes to mind anyway.